# Selenium funciona com o Firefox, mas não com o Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Estava utilizando normalmente o Firefox no Selenium com Python, mas queria fazer alguns testes utilizando o Google Chrome, então fiz a seguinte alteração:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Para

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Ele abre o Google Chrome mas logo em seguinte ele fecha e aparece esta mensagem no prompt:

> [6552:2280:1116/091247.001:ERROR:audio_manager_base.cc(275)] Invalid
>   audio output parameters received; using fake audio path. Channels: 0,
>   Sample Rate: 0, Bits Per Sample: 0, Frames Per Buffer: 0

Como nos meu testes eu não vou utilizar nada de áudio, tentei procurar algo para desativar, mas só encontrei como da 'mute' e mesmo com esta opção o erro foi o mesmo.

Pensei em passar algo no construtor para desativar o áudio, mas não tem nada para isso:

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
                 chrome_options=None, service_args=None,
                 desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None)
```

E a mensagem não informa de onde vem este tal arquivo 'audio_manager_base.cc', pesquisei na pasta do chrome na pasta do python e nada.

O drive que estou utilizando é o mais recente e o Google Chrome também.

Obs: O arquivo de log que é gerado pelo drive esta vazio.

**Update**

Durante a minha pesquisa vi que este erro do áudio acontecia não só no Selenium, então desconfiei, este erro acontece porque o plugin p2 do computador esta sem nada lá, simples assim, mas ainda não funciona, fui colocando um pause em cada linha para verificar o porque o Chrome fechava, então constatei que é na linha onde ele faz o screenshot, o mais estranho que ele não apresenta nenhum erro:

```
qr = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self._SELECTORS['qrCode'])
qr.screenshot(self.username+".png")
```

**Update**

Fiz uma alteração no código, agora ele tira o screenshot mas somente da tela inteira, eu preciso tirar somente de um elemento, mas com isso eu consegui continuar um pouco o fluxo do código, e descobri outro problema, ao executar um script:

```
Store = driver.execute_script(script)
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro ao tentar executar o script:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Maximum call stack size exceeded

[O problema que ele não consegue pegar um objeto muito grande de retorno do script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807075/protractor-jasmine-test-throws-unknownerror-unknown-error-maximum-call-stack/26034889#26034889)

Estou chegando a seguinte conclusão, que o drive para o Google Chrome é muito limitado em comparação ao do firefox, o código funciona muito bem no firefox, mas no Chrome acontecem estes problemas, em toda a minha pesquisa percebi que o problema é realmente limitação do drive, mas mesmo assim estou com esperança de esta enganado, por isso continuo com esta pergunta aqui.